# A multiple choice question on an $n \times n$ real matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ ne an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries. Pick out the true statements.
>
> 1. There exists a real symmetric $ n \times n$ matrix $B$ such that $B^{2} = A^{*}A$
> 2. If $A$ is symmetric, there exists a real symmetric $ n \times n$ matrix $B$ such that $ B^{2} = A$
> 3. If $A$ is symmetric, there exists a real symmetric $ n \times n$ matrix $B$ such that $ B^{3} = A$

My attempt:

Since every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, so I can write the matrix $A$ in the form of a diagonal matrix.

Let the diagonal form of $A =$ diag$(  a   b   c   d ......]$

For third option, I can always find another diagonal matrix $B =$ diag$[ a^{1/3}    b^{1/3}     c^{1/3}.....]$ so that $B^{3} = A$

For second option, such matrix can't be formed if eigen values of $A$ are negative.

I have no idea what to do with option 1.

Are my arguments correct for 2 and 3?

Any suggestion for option 1 would be helpful.

Comment: Does $A*A=A^2$? Or is it something else.

Comment: I edited it. $A^{*}$ is conjugate transpose of $A$

Comment: $A^{\ast} A$ has all its eigenvalues positive.

Comment: It’s a bad idea to use “A” to denote two things; in this case, the option and the matrix. Worse when you then use $A$ (rather than A) to refer to the option a few times.

Comment: Your argument for second and third option is correct, use the result that $A^*A$ is always positive definite symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question 2 and 3, you should say that there's an orthogonal matrix T so that
$A=T^*DT$ where $D=\mathrm{diag}\{ d_1, d_2,\ldots,d_t\}$. And we could define $B = T^*CT$ where $C=\mathrm{diag}\{d_1^1/3, d_2^{1/3}, \ldots, d_t^{1/3}\}$.

For question 1, since $A^*A$ is symmetric matrix and all eigenvalue is non-negative, similar to previous solution, we could find a symmetric $B$ so that $B^2=A^*A$